# Get memory usage in CentOS formatted

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What is the best way in `CentOS` via a shell command to get the memory usage/free memory formatted like:

```
Memory used: 389MB of 1024MB
```

I know about `free -m` but parsing it, provides a challenge.

Comment: Are you trying to feed this data through something else which requires that you have only 1 line? Otherwise, I don't see where the "challenge" lies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why `free -m` provides a challenge. Are you referring to the used memory without buffers & cache? Then free -m shows it in the 2nd line.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      >> 15929 <<   11394       4534          0        326       8871
-/+ buffers/cache:    >> 2197 <<   13732
Swap:         4095         38       4057
```

That would be equivalent to:

```
Memory used: 2197MB of 15929MB
```

Comment: So here is the total memory `free -m | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 |  awk '{ print $2 }'` and then used `free -m | head -n 3 | tail -n 1 |  awk '{ print $3 }'`. Is there a way to create a single liner to generate the format I want?

Comment: You could just make a new sh file with the command you wrote. So that it will output them in a single line. Then you can run that executable each time.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with `awk`:

```
$ free -m | awk '/Mem:/ {TOTAL=$2} /buffers/ {USED=$3} END {print "Memory used: " USED "MB of " TOTAL "MB"}'
Memory used: 6161MB of 7729MB
```